# Why $(window).width() get a wrong width?

Tags: jquery, mobile, width

I'm using jQuery to do animations in a site. In desktop browsers, the width that jquery give me is correctly but, when I use my mobile (has 360px of width), jQuery says that the browser has 980px of width..I do not understand the reason..

Some help?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your phone's browser doesn't see your site as responsive.

Add into your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: The label is already included in the code, but it still occurs the same.

Comment: @amelian: so please add a link to your page.